# The Primary Skill field value is blank on the Live Agent Transcript ever since 7/31/2014

Tags: liveagent

The standard **Primary Skill** field value on the Live Agent Transcript is now blank. This started on 7/31/2014. Prior to this date, the primary skill populated correctly. No changes were made in the Live Agent settings on SalesForce or our custom pre-chat form. It looks like the JavaScript API was updated on 7/18/2014. In the latest Developer's Guide, the JavaScript file referenced is older than what is on our deployment page in SalesForce (v29.0). We are currently using v31.0:

*our_hostname*.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/31.0/deployment.js

I confirmed that v29.0 doesn't make a difference, either.

We think the issue is on the SalesForce side, since it's a standard field that should populate based on the incoming skill. Also note that the skill correctly routes to the agent assigned to the skill.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was escalated to SalesForce's R&D team and has been added to their known issues list:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5RAAA0